# Generic Method in Non-Generic Interface

Tags: c#, oop, generics, interface

What is the difference between having a "Generic Interface" and "Generic method in non generic interface" ?
Is there any advantage of one over the other ?

```
interface IMyInterface
{
     void MyMethod<T>(T param) where T : class;
}
```

and

```
interface IMyInterface<T>  where T : class
{
   void MyMethod(T param)
}
```

Comment: The difference is the same like between generic class and non-generic class with generic methods.

Comment: Difference that with generic interface implementation of interface should be generic too or use concrete type. Where generic method can be used as generic and concrete type can be defined in runtime

Comment: It just depends on how you want to use the method and the type. There's little difference in your specific example, but in other cases you want a whole object to operate on the same type. Frankly, you won't see an _interface_ with generic _methods_ much, because an interface is usually about the whole object. But if you had a situation where you only wanted one or more methods in an interface, you'd make them generic, for the same reason you'd do that in a class. See marked duplicates for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the non-generic method can't force the generic method to have specific type parameters. The generic interface can.

In your `IMyInterface<T>.MyMethod`, `T` can only be the exact same type used by the `IMyInterface<T>`. In `IMyInterface.MyMethod`, `T` can be anything (as long as it obeys the type constraint `T : class`).

Comment: Thank you for you answer